# How does Dijkstra's algorithm work?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, discrete-mathematics

Can someone succinctly explain how Dijkstra's algorithm works and how it may be used to find the shortest path for such a graph (from a to z)?

[image: graph]

I've looked at some procedures online, but many of them seem to differ and it's hard to discern what I'm actually trying to accomplish.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The net is swarming with explanations of Dijkstra algorithm and I don't think we need yet another one here. On the other side, should you have any *concrete* questions, I will be glad to help.

Comment: If I were Edsger Dijkstra, I would be annoyed that my name was associated with such a transparent and obvious algorithm. As if I hadn't done anything better!

Comment: I tried to give some intuition along an answer to a previously asked question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45683/dijkstras-algorithm-proof/45702#45702

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 You will start from a and you will put a label 0. After that you will find all the unsolved nodes, like b (label 2) and c(label 3) . You will chose the node with the smallest label. So we will continue with b( label 2)
```

For now we have route a(0)-b(2);

- We continue to expand the unsolved nodes, so we will have: d((label b) + 5 = 7) ,e((label b) + 2 = 4) and c (label = 3). We will chose c because it has the smallest label.

  - We continue to expand the unsolved nodes, so we will have: d((label b) + 5 = 7) ,e((label b) + 2 = 4). We will chose e because it has the smallest label ."4"

    - We continue to expand the unsolved nodes, so we will have: d((label e) + 1 = 5) ,z((label e) + 4 = 8). We will chose d because it has the smallest label ."5"
    - We continue to expand the unsolved nodes, so we will have: z((label e) + 4 = 8). We will chose z because it has the smallest label ."8"

Maybe this tutorial will help you: http://optlab-server.sce.carleton.ca/POAnimations2007/DijkstrasAlgo.html